# GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES Not working on OpenGL ES 3.0 NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am working on a NDK project and I had to support API 19 and I migrated from 2.0 to 3.0 OpenGL ES for need graphical applicaiton needs and now I am getting an error drawing to the screen with `GL_TEXTURE_2D` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`

I have not found anywhere saying `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` is not supported in 3.0 yet I get an error when trying to compile and nothing is displaying with `GL_TEXTURE_2D`

Answer (score 1):

GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES is supported on OpenGL ES 3.0, but there was some problem with the headers (gl2ext.h) that was fixed in a later API level (21 I believe). You should make sure you are including the correct headers - take a look here for a workaround for your API level: [GLES 3.0 including gl2ext.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003863/gles-3-0-including-gl2ext-h)